# How is this logo design flawed?

Tags: logo

Without googling the company to see what it does, explain how this logo design is flawed, and what changes could be made to correct it while still conveying the idea of chemistry.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Robyn. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at our [guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An opinion, no proof cannot be given:

it's business name ilamar Coatings. Probably something else is wanted, perhaps Milamar Coatings, but the chemical lab stuff symbol is too different. Maybe some wider font helps.

One example how to integrate the parts:

[image]

If you want to keep all other texts at the right side of the M as it was, then you can try this:

[image]

(please, ignore the deformations caused to M, I tried to drag it higher except the black drop, which seemed too big)

EDIT: Altough forbidden, I finally checked the website. Its opening page has finer logo than my coarse attempts. The brochures have nearly the same as there's included in the question. If the actual problem was "should the brochures get the new logo?" my answer is YES!

Answer (score 1):

This is a highly subjective question, and difficult to answer without merely being personal opinion. I'll try to avoid that and comment on some problems with the main part of the logo which many here will probably notice.

The main graphic needs some refining since it looks a bit uneven. I get that these are chemical flasks inside the M shape, by the way.

Here are some problems I noticed.

[image]

1 and 2 - the curved lips of the flask are different sizes on each side, which makes the flask look lopsided.

3 and 4 - These corner points should be on the same horizontal plane

5 - this corner point is too sharp, a curve would be better here.

Comment: Funny, the only thing about it that really bothered me is that the contents of the flask has a different shape from the flask itself. Made me wonder what that weird black lump of clot was, and how they got it into the flask.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes I noticed that too, I suppose that could be problem No. 6.